# How can I use django to realize real time?

Tags: python, django, websocket, real-time, rethinkdb

I have a rethinkdb. Data will get in database for every five minutes.
I want to create a website to real-time inspect this data flow from rethinkdb.
That is, when surfing the webpage, the data from db on webpages can update automatically without refreshing the webpage.
I know there are several ways to make it real-time such as django channels or websockets. However, model in django does not support rethinkdb.

Sorry I am a layman of making website and may express things inaccurately.
Can someone give me a keyword or hint?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you strictly want to build it with Django? Otherwise, I'll recommend Meteor (backend to frontend reactivity automatically built-in) or AngularJS with Firebase. In simple terms with Django, you'll need to have a front-end script that'll be pulling data from the server at intervals of your choice.

Comment: https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/tree/master/liveblog
sor, I didnt ask the question specifically. The example I used is above. My plan is that using r.table('table_name').change().run() would allow me to know the new data input and I want to put it on websocket(onmessage or something) to do real-time stuff.However, although I can connect my rethinkdb, I dont know how to connect it to websocket in this example. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: @tinjuiho I would ask a new question with this code and these new specifics

Answer (score 2):

If you make your question more specific, the community here will be able to offer you better support.

However, here is a general solution to your problem.

You will need to do two things:

1. **Create a backend API** that allows you to:

   - Check if new data has been added to the database
   - Fetch new data via a REST api request
2. Make **frontend AJAX requests** to this api

   - Fetch data
   - Periodically (every 30sec) check if there is new data
   - Fetch data again if new data is detected

To do this using Django as the backend, I would recommend using the [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to create your API.

This API should have two endpoints:

1. ListView of your data
2. Endpoint returning the id and timestamp of the last datapoint

Next you will have to create a frontend that uses javascript to make requests to these endpoints. When you fetch data, store the id and timestamp of the most recent data point. Use this to check if there is new data.

I would recommend using a Javascript framework such as [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) or [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) but depending on your needs these may be overkill.

**EDIT:**

Now that you have updated your answer to be more specific, here is my advice. It sounds like your number one priority is rethinkDB and real time data. Django is not well suited this because it is not compatible with rethinkDB. Real time support has come a long way in Django with Django channels however.

It sounds like you are early on in your project and have little to no codebase in Django. I would recommend using [horizon](https://horizon.io/) along with rethink db. Horizon is a javascript backend built for real time data from rethinkdb.